# How do I show $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous without compactness?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm a little lost on where to go after the using the identity
$|\sqrt[3]{x_1}-\sqrt[3]{x_2}|=\frac{x_1-x_2}{|\sqrt[3]{x_1^2}+\sqrt[3]{x_1x_2}+\sqrt[3]{x_2^2}|}$.

Comment: 1. First deal with the case where $x=0$. 2. Assuming now that $x_2$ is not zero, find a *lower bound* for the denominator of your expression, subject to $x_1$ being close enough to $x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for helping! So in the case that $x_1$ is $0$, we get $\delta<\epsilon^3$. I'm not exactly sure how to find this lower bound. I tried limiting $\delta<1$, but the resulting expression with the triangle inequality doesn't look very helpful. Since it is uniformly continuous, shouldn't there be a minimum delta independent of $x_1$?

Comment: If $x_2\ne0$, then by picking $\delta=|x_2|/2$ you have that if $|x_1-x_2|<\delta$, then $|x_1|\ge |x_2|/2$. This gives you the lower bound you need. You do not need to pick the delta I suggest, of course. All you need is some $\delta$ that ensures that $x_1$ is *away* from $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove, similar to the inverted triangle inequality, that

$$|\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]y|\le\sqrt[3]{|x-y|}$$

Start by assuming $y=x+h>x\ge 0$ and apply the binomial formula for the third power.

This works for any power of the root.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "inverted triangle inequality"? After expanding, I get $|x-y|+|-3\sqrt[3]{x^2}\sqrt[3]{y}+3\sqrt[3]{x}\sqrt[3]{y^2}|\geq|\sqrt[3]{x}-\sqrt[3]{y}|^3$, but this doesn't show the identity you've mentioned

Comment: Just the strategy to combine the final inequality from the two cases $x<y$ and $y\le x$. The first case leads to $\sqrt[3]{x+h}\le \sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{h}$, by symmetry, the second case follows.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having trouble establishing this identity when $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs. For example, the identity seems to fail when $x=8, y=-1$?

Comment: Yes, this inequality only works for the standard definition of root, i.e., where it is restricted to non-negative arguments.